# Using an addEventListener instead of inline 'onclick' event in the img tag

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to use one JavaScript event listener to trigger these modal windows instead of applying one `onclick` events for multiple images.

```html
<div class="full-img-modal">
  <img src="img/gallery-images/gallery-img-01.jpg" alt="" id="full-img">
  <span class="close-gallery fa-solid fa-circle-xmark" onclick="closeFullImgModal()"></span>
</div>

<div class="img-gallery">
  <img src="img/gallery-images/gallery-img-01.jpg" alt="" class="img-thumb" onclick="openFullImgModal(this.src)">
  <img src="img/gallery-images/gallery-img-02.jpg" alt="" class="img-thumb" onclick="openFullImgModal(this.src)">
  <img src="img/gallery-images/gallery-img-03.jpg" alt="" class="img-thumb" onclick="openFullImgModal(this.src)">
  <img src="img/gallery-images/gallery-img-04.jpg" alt="" class="img-thumb" onclick="openFullImgModal(this.src)">
  <img src="img/gallery-images/gallery-img-05.jpg" alt="" class="img-thumb" onclick="openFullImgModal(this.src)">
  <img src="img/gallery-images/gallery-img-06.jpg" alt="" class="img-thumb" onclick="openFullImgModal(this.src)">
  <img src="img/gallery-images/gallery-img-07.jpg" alt="" class="img-thumb" onclick="openFullImgModal(this.src)">
  <img src="img/gallery-images/gallery-img-08.jpg" alt="" class="img-thumb" onclick="openFullImgModal(this.src)">
</div>
```

```js
const fullImgModal = document.querySelector('.full-img-modal');
const fullImg = document.querySelector('#full-img');
const closeGallery = document.querySelector('.close-gallery');

function openFullImgModal(photo) {
  fullImgModal.style.display = "flex";
  fullImg.src = photo;
}

function closeFullImgModal() {
  fullImgModal.style.display = "none";
}

window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target == fullImgModal) {
    fullImgModal.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

GitHub link:
https://github.com/rovingCondor/photo-gallery.git

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: `document.querySelector` will return only the first element that matches the selector. You want to check in the event handler if `event.target` matches that selector. Since you're targeting void `<img>` elements, you can use directly `Element#matches()`, but generally it's preferred to use `.closest()` to also catch clicks on descendants of the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using event delegation from a parent element is indeed a great idea, not only to reduce the listeners added to element, but it also helps in achieving listeners to dynamically added elements into the DOM.
PS: use `Element.classList` to add, remove, toggle CSS classes instead of `Element.style` - styles should be in CSS, not in JS.

```js
const fullImgModal = document.querySelector('.full-img-modal');
const fullImg = document.querySelector('#full-img');
const closeGallery = document.querySelector('.close-gallery');

addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  const elTHumb = event.target.closest(".img-thumb")
  if (!elTHumb) return; // Do nothing. Not our thumbnail.
  fullImg.src = elTHumb.src;
  fullImgModal.classList.add("is-open");
});

closeGallery.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fullImgModal.classList.remove("is-open");
});
```

```css
.img-thumb {
  height: 5rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  object-fit: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.full-img-modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  padding: 1rem;
  backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  opacity: 0;
  scale: 1.1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, scale 0.5s;
}

.full-img-modal.is-open {
  opacity: 1;
  scale: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

#full-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.close-gallery {
  all: unset;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2rem;
  top: 0rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-img-modal">
  <img src="#!" alt="" id="full-img">
  <button type="button" class="close-gallery fa-solid fa-circle-xmark">&times;</button>
</div>

<div class="img-gallery">
  <img src="https://placedog.net/500" alt="" class="img-thumb">
  <img src="https://placedog.net/600" alt="" class="img-thumb">
  <img src="https://placedog.net/700" alt="" class="img-thumb">
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the efficient and scalable solution. Appreciate the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

This is not very pretty but that was not part of the question.  Here we used some script to add an event listener to various things.

```js
const fullImgModal = document.querySelector('.full-img-modal');
const fullImg = document.querySelector('#full-img');
const closeGallery = document.querySelector('.close-gallery');
const allThumbs = document.querySelectorAll('.img-thumb');
allThumbs.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', openInModal));
closeGallery.addEventListener('click', closeFullImgModal);

function openInModal(event) {
  console.log(event.target.alt, event.target.src);
  openFullImgModal(event.target.src)
}

function openFullImgModal(photo) {
  fullImg.src = photo;
  fullImgModal.dataset.showme = "show";
}

function closeFullImgModal() {
  fullImgModal.style.display = "none";
}
/* not used
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.currentTarget == fullImgModal) {
    fullImgModal.style.display = "none";
  }
});*/
```

```css
.full-img-modal {
  display: none;
}

.full-img-modal[data-showme="show"] {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.close-gallery {
  border: solid 1px red;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-img-modal">
  <img src="img/gallery-images/gallery-img-01.jpg" alt="xx" id="full-img">
  <span class="close-gallery fa-solid fa-circle-xmark">X</span>
</div>

<div class="img-gallery">
  <img src="img/gallery-images/gallery-img-01.jpg" alt="1" class="img-thumb">
  <img src="img/gallery-images/gallery-img-02.jpg" alt="2" class="img-thumb">
  <img src="img/gallery-images/gallery-img-03.jpg" alt="3" class="img-thumb">
  <img src="img/gallery-images/gallery-img-04.jpg" alt="4" class="img-thumb">
  <img src="img/gallery-images/gallery-img-05.jpg" alt="5" class="img-thumb">
  <img src="img/gallery-images/gallery-img-06.jpg" alt="6" class="img-thumb">
  <img src="img/gallery-images/gallery-img-07.jpg" alt="7" class="img-thumb">
  <img src="img/gallery-images/gallery-img-08.jpg" alt="8" class="img-thumb">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "querySelectorAll('.img-thumb')" to select all the image thumbnails and store them in a new variable ei. "const imgThumbs = document.querySelectorAll('.img-thumb');". Then, use "forEach" to iterate over each "imgThumb" and attach a click event listener. Inside the listener, call the "openFullImgModal" function with "this.src" as the argument to pass the source of the clicked image. Now you can erase all those "onclick"